# Unable to read space between the characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have JSON data by which I am trying to populate the HTML table. Earlier the table was populating fine but as per my requirement, I have changed my code.

**What I am doing**

- I have a `form` inside which I have a select option (drop-down) and my Table
- While creating the table I am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row
- So that when user selects any drop-down option I am showing the data of that category only and hiding others,but i am getting error while adding the class
- Error is `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character`
- I don't know what i am doing wrong

**Snippet**

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1978",
    "Item Name": "Alu Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1979",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Alu Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1980",
    "Item Name": "Samosa-S",
    "Selling Price": "25.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1981",
    "Item Name": "SamosaChat-S",
    "Selling Price": "40.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1982",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Samosa Chats-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1983",
    "Item Name": "Garam Samosa Chats-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1984",
    "Item Name": "Kachori Chats-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1985",
    "Item Name": "Garam Kachori Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1986",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Kachori Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1987",
    "Item Name": "Dai Raj Kachori-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1988",
    "Item Name": "Baby Kachori Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1989",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Baby Kachori-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1990",
    "Item Name": "Anar Bhalla-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1991",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Bhalla-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1992",
    "Item Name": "Jhal Muri-S",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1993",
    "Item Name": "Chat Platter-S",
    "Selling Price": "110.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1994",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Papdi Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2402",
    "Item Name": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "Selling Price": "26.2000",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "333",
    "Item Name": "A BR SB EX",
    "Selling Price": "1.0000",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  }
]


function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      //here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row. 
      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.classList.add(categoryName);

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
        quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {

        if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Selling Price'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Category Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Category_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTable(tableData);

$('#CategoryName').on('change', function() {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  console.log(selectedOption);
  //getting all item rows so i can target them.
  var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

  if (selectedOption === 'All') {
    //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  } else {
    //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
    // firstly i am style all rows with visibility: collapse
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
    }
    // then getting all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
    var selectedItemRows = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedOption);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
      selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="form1" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Chats</option>
          <option>GIFT PACK</option>
          <option>EXEMPTED</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
      <button id="clear">
     <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Clear
    </button>
      <!-- <button id="print" type="button" onclick="printFunction()">
     <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print
    </button> -->
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

1. The error I am getting because when category name comes as gift pack, it is not reading the space.
2. It's giving the error as invalid character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error:

```
// ...
"Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
// ...
var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
tr.classList.add(categoryName)
```

You are trying to add `"GIFT PACK"` as a class of an element; but no class name can contain spaces. E.g. when you write `<tr class="GIFT PACK">`, the element gets *two* classes: `GIFT` and `PACK`. When you write `.GIFT PACK` in CSS, you are looking for an element `<PACK>` that is inside an element with a class `GIFT`. There is no way for a class name to contain a space, and JavaScript is reporting an error because you're forcing it to do something impossible.

EDIT: Per comments.

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1978",
    "Item Name": "Alu Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1979",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Alu Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1980",
    "Item Name": "Samosa-S",
    "Selling Price": "25.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1981",
    "Item Name": "SamosaChat-S",
    "Selling Price": "40.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1982",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Samosa Chats-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1983",
    "Item Name": "Garam Samosa Chats-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1984",
    "Item Name": "Kachori Chats-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1985",
    "Item Name": "Garam Kachori Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1986",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Kachori Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1987",
    "Item Name": "Dai Raj Kachori-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1988",
    "Item Name": "Baby Kachori Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1989",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Baby Kachori-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1990",
    "Item Name": "Anar Bhalla-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1991",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Bhalla-S",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1992",
    "Item Name": "Jhal Muri-S",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1993",
    "Item Name": "Chat Platter-S",
    "Selling Price": "110.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1994",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Papdi Chat-S",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2402",
    "Item Name": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "Selling Price": "26.2000",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "333",
    "Item Name": "A BR SB EX",
    "Selling Price": "1.0000",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  }
]


function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      //here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row. 
      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.setAttribute('data-category', categoryName);

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
        quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {

        if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Selling Price'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Category Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Category_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTable(tableData);

$('#CategoryName').on('change', function() {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  //getting all item rows so i can target them.
  var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

  if (selectedOption === 'All') {
    //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  } else {
    //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
    // firstly i am style all rows with visibility: collapse
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
    }
    // then getting all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
    var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll('[data-category="' + selectedOption + '"');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
      selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="form1" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Chats</option>
          <option>GIFT PACK</option>
          <option>EXEMPTED</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
      <button id="clear">
     <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Clear
    </button>
      <!-- <button id="print" type="button" onclick="printFunction()">
     <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print
    </button> -->
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

EDIT2: Even more radical approach: you can just get *all* `item-row`, iterate each, and set their visibility according to what they should be; there is no need to have browser filter your items.

Comment: is there any alternative for this ,because on change of select option i am hidding other rows and showing categories which are selected

Comment: Why do you need it to be `class`? Why not an attribute? `tr.setAttribute('data-category', categoryName)`; then instead of `var selectedItemRows = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedOption);`, you can do `var selectedItemRows = document.querySelector('[data-category="' + selectedOption + '"]');`? Attributes don't have restrictions like classes do.

Comment: hey can you please add some sort of working snippet,as i have done what you said but not getting the expected output

Comment: Eh, should've been `querySelectorAll`. Snippet inserted. The point is, shouldn't use classes for what they're not designed to do (hold arbitrary information).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is in `tr.classList.add(categoryName);`

A css class cannot contain a space, plain and simple.

Comment: so what can i do to overcome this because i have to provide class or id here,and this is coming from my db where space is there between two strings

Comment: Use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) probably change the ` ` with `_`. Example: `string.replace(" ", "_");`

Comment: @viveksingh in between `var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];`
   and   `tr.classList.add(categoryName);` change your categoryName space there

Comment: either strip the spaces and run the risk of collision with GIFTPACK, or convert to underscore and run the risk of collision with GIFT_PACK,  or the same with GIFT-PACK, or GIFT__PACK, etc, etc,etc.  Or rethink your entire approach.... Maybe build a mapping table between the name you get from the db and, say "class0", "class1", "class2", etc...

Comment: @Mukyuu @viveksingh , that isn't sufficient.  You also need to add it to `    var selectedItemRows = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedOption);`  where you find the rows to display

Comment: @LeroyStav how can i achieve this by maping,can you please help me out,any kind of help will be appreciated please

Comment: It depends entirely on what, exactly, you need.  Do you need a distinct class per category, or is that just the arbitrary decision you made?  If you don't need it then, actually, the suggestions in other answers of using `data-` attributes is a better way to go.  If you *do* need it, then I would ask if the categories are well-known?  If so, then you have `var categoryClasses = {'CATEGORY NAME 1', 'class_for_category_1', 'CATEGORY NAME 2', `'class_for_cat_2', ...};` and instead of where you currently use `categoryName` for class names, use `categoryClasses[categoryName]`.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
tr.classList.add(categoryName);`
```

with this

```
tr.classList.add(categoryName.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase());
```

### Update

if you don't want to change your category name, you can use data attribute for your filter.

**from add class list to add dataset**

```
// tr.classList.add(categoryName);
tr.dataset.category = categoryName;
```

**from select by class name to select by data set**

```
// var selectedItemRows = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedOption);
var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");
```

```js
  var tableData = [
    {
      "Item Code": "1978",
      "Item Name": "Alu Chat-S",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1979",
      "Item Name": "Dahi Alu Chat-S",
      "Selling Price": "50.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1980",
      "Item Name": "Samosa-S",
      "Selling Price": "25.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1981",
      "Item Name": "SamosaChat-S",
      "Selling Price": "40.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1982",
      "Item Name": "Dahi Samosa Chats-S",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1983",
      "Item Name": "Garam Samosa Chats-S",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1984",
      "Item Name": "Kachori Chats-S",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1985",
      "Item Name": "Garam Kachori Chat-S",
      "Selling Price": "50.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1986",
      "Item Name": "Dahi Kachori Chat-S",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1987",
      "Item Name": "Dai Raj Kachori-S",
      "Selling Price": "65.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1988",
      "Item Name": "Baby Kachori Chat-S",
      "Selling Price": "65.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1989",
      "Item Name": "Dahi Baby Kachori-S",
      "Selling Price": "65.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1990",
      "Item Name": "Anar Bhalla-S",
      "Selling Price": "65.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1991",
      "Item Name": "Dahi Bhalla-S",
      "Selling Price": "65.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1992",
      "Item Name": "Jhal Muri-S",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1993",
      "Item Name": "Chat Platter-S",
      "Selling Price": "110.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "1994",
      "Item Name": "Dahi Papdi Chat-S",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Category Name": "Chats"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "2402",
      "Item Name": "ALMOND CHBAR",
      "Selling Price": "26.2000",
      "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
    },
    {
      "Item Code": "333",
      "Item Name": "A BR SB EX",
      "Selling Price": "1.0000",
      "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
    }
  ];

  function addTable(tableData) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
    var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
    for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      if (i >= colNum) {
        th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
        tr.appendChild(th);
        tr.classList.add("text-center");
        tr.classList.add("head");
      } else {
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
        tr.classList.add("text-center");
        tr.classList.add("head");
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      tr.classList.add("item-row");
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
        //here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row.
        var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
        tr.dataset.category = categoryName;

        let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.style.display = "none";
        var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
        if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {
          var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
          quantityField.style.border = "none";
          quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
          quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
          quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", "0");
          quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
          quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
          quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
          tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
        } else {
          if (tableData[i]["Item Code"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
            tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Code");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
            tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
          }
          if (tableData[i]["Item Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
            tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Name");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
            tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
          }
          if (tableData[i]["Selling Price"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
            tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Selling_Price");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
            tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
          }
          if (tableData[i]["Category Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
            tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Category_Name");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
            tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
          }
          if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
        }
      }
    }
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");
    table.classList.add("table-hover");
  }
  addTable(tableData);

  $("#CategoryName").on("change", function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    console.log(selectedOption);
    //getting all item rows so i can target them.
    var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

    if (selectedOption === "All") {
      //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
      for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
        itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    } else {
      //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
      // firstly i am style all rows with visibility: collapse
      for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
        itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
      }
      // then getting all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
      var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");

      for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
        selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="form1" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Chats</option>
          <option>GIFT PACK</option>
          <option>EXEMPTED</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black" />
    <div class="table-responsive"><table class="w-100" id="HourlysalesSummary"></table></div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
      <button id="clear"><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Clear</button>
      <!-- <button id="print" type="button" onclick="printFunction()">
     <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print
    </button> -->
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey now its not hiding the table rows when i am selecting any drop-down,because when user selects Gift Pack so it doesn't matches with Gift_Pack,so no table formed when user selects dropdown

Comment: @viveksingh I've updated my code, because you can't change category name, i suggest you to use data attribute and and use it for filter.

Answer (score 0):

classList.add(tokens...) does not accepts ASCII whitespace in 'tokens' parameter. You could replace whitespace for '-', like mentioned in other answers. This is how I would change the code (I added 'replace()'):

> `//here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row. 
>         var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
>         tr.classList.add(categoryName.replace(" ", "-"));`
>
> `$('#CategoryName').on('change', function() {
>     var selectedOption = this.value.replace(" ", "-");
>     console.log(selectedOption.replace(" ", "-"));`

`The classList attribute’s getter must return a DOMTokenList object whose associated element is the context object and whose associated attribute’s local name is class. The token set of this particular DOMTokenList object are also known as the element’s classes.`
source: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-classlist

`If token contains any ASCII whitespace, then throw an "InvalidCharacterError" DOMException.`
source: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-domtokenlist-add

Comment: i know that's why i have put up the question to find some alternative